# Ansys Fluent Journal If-Else and Do Statement

Tags: ansys

I'm using Ansys 2020 R2 version and I have a parametrical model and I want to crate lines in fluent post-processing side. Since I have a lot of lines and these line coordinates are change according to the geometry I wonder if is there any way to syncronize these lines in fluent ?

For example let say I have "width","height" as input geometrical parameters and in Fluent I can create lines using 'Journal' I wonder is there any way to use "if-else" and "do" statement with using "input parameters"
I will write a code which read width,height parameters and decide which lines will be created?

Just I wonder is there any way to use "if-else" and "do" statement in Ansys Fluent Journal File